# bibtex8: open_op_file error

Tags: bibtex

### `bibtex8` file open error

When I launch `bibtex8` under Windows 7, it terminates with a fatal error:

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin>bibtex8.exe -d io -c cp1251.csf C:\Users\
skobls\Documents\ComSet\ComSet
D-I/O: open_ip_file: trying to open `C:/Users/skobls/Documents/ComSet/ComSet.aux
' ...
D-I/O: open_op_file: trying to open `C:\Users\skobls\Documents\ComSet\ComSet.blg
' ...
open_op_file: error opening `C:\Users\skobls\Documents\ComSet\ComSet.blg'
I couldn't open file name `C:\Users\skobls\Documents\ComSet\ComSet.blg'
(That was a fatal error)
```

Can this be cured somehow? Changing compatibility modes and privilege level doesn't help. The error remains even when `.blg` file doesn't exist.

Comment: Why do you start bibtex in the `bin` folder? Switch to the document folder (`ComSet`) and then try `bibtex8 -d io -c cp1251.csf ComSet`. Absolute pathes are always a possible source of problems.

Comment: I did it so, because it is how `TeXnicCenter` does it.
Now I've tried Ulrike's advice - it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

The solution here is to use relative path.

In `TeXnicCenter` the correct arguments for `BibTeX` are following:

Path to BibTeX executable:

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\bibtex8.exe
```

Command line arguments to pass to BibTeX:

```
-B -c cp1251.csf "%tm"
```